# Markdown in Visual Studio Code

Tags: markdown, visual-studio-code

I've been writing markdown files in VScode recently, and although it seems very nice, I am having a few issues that I can't overcome.

I am trying to write markdown in VScode and see accurate results, then export that to HTML while keeping all styling. My issues are:

1. In preview mode, I can't get get syntax highlighting for code to work. In markdown view, the syntax highlighting does work, but in preview it just shows up as plain text in a gray box.  (I am currently specifically looking for VB)
2. How to export to HTML with styles? I followed the [instructions](http://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/markdown#_compiling-markdown-into-html) to export to HTML and it works, but the export is very basic and no styling is applied. Also, for code blocks, keywords are not separated for different styles!

I've spent hours on the VScode docs, as well as on the github issues, but I found nothing.
What is the proper method of work to

Any help will be very much appreciated!
Thanks!

---

**EDIT :**
Here is a screenshot of what I am seeing. You can see that on the left side, I am getting syntax highlighting for Python, but not for VBnet, and on the right side, I am not getting any syntax highlighting.

[image]

Comment: Can you post specifically what you are seeing? There are limitations with the tool and what we may need to do is make a feature request in Github.

Comment: Sure - I edited my post with a link and description. - Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bug with the Video Studio Code preview, as it should support GitHub flavored Markdown.

You said you looked at the GitHub issues, did you try submitting one yourself?

Comment: no, I haven't submitted an issue on github yet. I guess I always feel that I'm just doing something wrong....  :)  - I will post this. Thanks

Comment: This does look like a bug. Davey opened an issue to track this: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3692